# HTML code in PlatesPHP

Tags: php, html

I'm using PlatesPHP on a very basic level with static data rather than extracting it from db.

In my controller I have:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.pkp';
echo $templates->render('index', [
    'project_1_checklist_point_1_help' => '<a href="google.com">Google</a>',
]);
```

and then in the index.php the following

```
<p><?=$this->e($project_1_checklist_point_1_help)?></p>
```

and in the template.php standard html skeleton.

It shows up as

> `<a href="google.com">Google</a>`

rather than a link, which I want.

> Google

I've tried htmlentity() and htmlspecialchars(), but they are not what I was looking for at all.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the un-escaped string, just echo the variable without the method `$this->e()`:

```
<p><?= $project_1_checklist_point_1_help ?></p>
```

The method `$this->e()` (short for `$this->escape()`) is equal to `htmlspecialchars()`, which html-encodes the string.

You can read more in depth about it the manual: http://platesphp.com/templates/escaping/

Comment: That's perfect! Cheers!